# Start Manual Sharepoint designer workflow using SPFX

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, spfx-extensions

Can we create spfx extension or webpart which can initiate workflow on selected items in document library

Answer (score 0):

Install the **modern script editor** web part from this link :[Add The Script Editor Web part back to SharePoint Modern Experience](https://medium.com/niftit-sharepoint-blog/add-the-script-editor-webpart-back-to-sharepoint-modern-experience-688a7b7208e4)

Then use the below javascript code :

```
    < script type = "text/javascript" > // <![CDATA[var PlumsailDemo = PlumsailDemo || {}; PlumsailDemo.WFPack = PlumsailDemo.WFPack || {};  

PlumsailDemo.WFPack.API = (function() {  
    var self = this;  
    self.Context = null,  
    self.WFManager = null;  

    SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function() {  
        SP.SOD.registerSod('sp.workflowservices.js', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.workflowservices.js'));  
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.workflowservices.js', "SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager",  

        function() {  
            self.Context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
            var web = self.Context.get_web();  
            self.WFManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(self.Context, web);  
        });  
    });  

    StartListWorkflowOnSelectedItems = function(subID) {  
        var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(self.Context);  

        for (item in selectedItems) {  
            var itemId = selectedItems[item].id;  
            self.StartListWorkflow(itemId, subID);  
        }  
    };  

    StartListWorkflow = function(itemID, subID) {  
        var subscription = self.WFManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().getSubscription(subID);  

        self.Context.load(subscription);  
        self.Context.executeQueryAsync(  

        function(sender, args) {  
            var inputParameters = {};  

            self.WFManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflowOnListItem(subscription, itemID, inputParameters);  

            self.Context.executeQueryAsync(  

            function(sender, args) {  
                var message = "The workflow " + subscription.get_name() + " was started on item with ID " + itemID;  
                SP.UI.Notify.addNotification(message, false);  
            },  

            function(sender, args) {  
                var message = "Failed to start workflow " + subscription.get_name() + " on item with ID " + itemID;  
                SP.UI.Notify.addNotification(message, false);  
                console.log("Failed to start workflow.");  
                console.log("Error: " + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());  
            });  
        },  

        function(sender, args) {  
            var message = "Failed to load subscription " + subID;  
            SP.UI.Notify.addNotification(message, false);  
            console.log("Failed to load subscription.");  
            console.log("Error: " + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());  
        });  

    };  

    return {  
        StartListWorkflow: StartListWorkflow,  
        StartListWorkflowOnSelectedItems: StartListWorkflowOnSelectedItems  
    };  
})();  
// ]]></script>
```

Source :

[How to Start SharePoint 2013 Workflows on Selected Items](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/77f269/how-to-start-sharepoint-2013-workflows-on-selected-items/)

Comment: Hi - if this has helped you, could you please mark this as answered, so that it will help to the upcoming visitors.